Having issues sending transaction on Safe App on Base
I am having issues trying to send transactions using safe app on Base. It says that "safe app couldn't be initialized" for this but I have the latest version available for Base. On our app it works perfectly fine connecting with . but those kind of odd things makes me confusing.
Proxy Factory: 0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC 1.3.0
Singleton: 0xfb1bffC9d739B8D520DaF37dF666da4C687191EA 1.3.0+L2



This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated Wallet support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page and explain the problem to them.
This stack exchange is more intended to be used for developers having trouble building on top of Safe{Core}.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
